# After calling render in the controller, when does the next line get called? Yii - PHP

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, yii

So, I'm trying to figure out what is the exact order/timing of functions being called in my controller in Yii. Right now, I have code like this

```
public function actionIndex()
{

    $userId = Login::model()->getUserId(); 

    // update all of the account balances upon viewing
   // Account::model()->updateAccountBalance($userId);

    // limits the data provided to only those accounts that are of the same userId 
    $dataProvider= new CActiveDataProvider('Account', array('criteria'=>array(
                                            'condition'=>'user_id="'.$userId.'"')));
    $this->render('index',array(
        'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
    ));
        // an attempt to update my account after the view has rendered.
        // nope this is super super slow. 
    Account::model()->updateAccountBalance($userId);

}
```

Which I would like to update my account balance in the database *after* everything in the view has been rendered. (In my view I have a couple of calls using Ajax to external servers.). Now, this seems to be working well - and it seems to be going as fast as it was using javascript initially. But, I'm still a bit confused on the order. Is my function

```
Account::model()->updateAccountBalance($userId);
```

being called *after* the view has entirely rendered (i.e. made ajax calls)? I know that there are specific functions like afterRender and filters  - but does this function get called after rendering anyways?

Comment: rendering just means the html is output to the browser. Once that is done, the next line is executed. How long the browser takes to run any js is outside your control.

Comment: But will the browser run the js before the other line is executed?

Comment: 99% no, it will not. But thats not guaranteed. As the js is ran on an entirely different computer (the clients pc, rather than the server) you cant be certain what will complete 1st. If you code relies on one finishing before the other you need to refactor

Comment: If you make this the answer - I'd totally accept that. Thank you!

Comment: Though, could you explain what you mean by refactor? Are you saying apply a filter?

Comment: updateAccountBalance has a call to a remote server - the call itself takes awhile because there are a large number of checks that need to be passed.

Answer (score 1):

Watching your Codes its 100% for sure, `Account::model()->updateAccountBalance($userId);` is not called. `$this->render();` will `exit` after your view was rendered successful. You can also check the Documentation about `render();` here: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CController#render-detail

By adding, true as return param to `$this->render();` you will be able to provide your application to "exit" after the view is rendered. But in that way, you will be get your "delay" again.

```
$viewData = $this->render('index',array(
    'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
), true);

// an attempt to update my account after the view has rendered.
// nope this is super super slow. 
Account::model()->updateAccountBalance($userId);

echo $viewData;
```

You should run `Account::model()->updateAccountBalance($userId);` in an own thread triggered by AJAX (clientside) or CRON (Backend) to make that async process work fine without any "delays".

I hope this will help you out.